# What is the sound of nails scratching a chalkboard called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does the high-pitched sound of nails scratching a chalkboard have a name?

I thought of "squeaking" or "screeching" but I don't think either of them correctly describes it.

Comment: Sheer torture!  Just kidding, I have no idea what it's called.  Screeching is about the best I could come up with but I'm not totally happy with it either.

Comment: Screeching isn't a name, but rather a description of the sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writers tend to use the phrase *[nails on a chalkboard](http://www.wordnik.com/words/nails%20on%20a%20chalkboard)* to describe the sound:

> “The music of veteran pop singer Cliff Richard apparently is like
>   *nails on a chalkboard* to hooligans.” [CNN]

Apparently, nobody has been able to capture the sound's singular power to excruciate in an onomatopoeia.

Comment: If the word were onomatopoeic, it would hardly be used, would it?

Comment: @JeffSahol I'd have a word to describe my neighbor's voice...

Comment: Hey what would an onomatopoeic word for *silence* sound like?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there was a lovely poetic term like _tintinnabulation_ or _susurrus_.

Comment: I've always heard "fingernails on a blackboard".

Answer (score 2):

I would call it chalkboard screech.

Answer (score 2):

Since there really isn't just *one* word that captures the true essence of the sound, how about slapping an adjective on the front? E.g. *shrill screech*.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the onomatopoeia "scree".

The sound this describes is common in many videogames and movies with pterosaur-like animals; it always reminded me (unpleasantly) of nails on a chalkboard.

> Her nails on the chalkboard made a shrill "SCREEEEEE" that sent shivers down my spine.

A somewhat-related video for reference: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5hrMdtOmrU&feature=related
(The sound I'm describing can be heard starting at 0:10).

Answer (score 1):

I like the sound of 'screak', because of that 'k'. The Oxford English Dictionary's examples don't mention blackboards, but do mention violins.

Answer (score 0):

*Chill-sending screech.*

I would say "chill-sending screech" because of the way nails on a chalkboard send chills down one's back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some kind of grating screech? Or try and describe the effects of the sound- perhaps by comparing it to the scraping of fingernails down the insides of your ears???

Answer (score -1):

Chill-sending screech.

I would describe the sound nails make running against a chalkboard as a "chill-sending screech" because, as we all know, the sound sends chills down your back.

Ex: The teacher made a chill-sending noise when she slid her nails against the chalkboard.